# Nigerian Visa on Arrival for Kenyan Citizen

Tags: visas-on-arrival, kenya, nigeria

I am a Kenyan planning to travel to Nigeria early next year for like 3 days. I am concerned about this Visa On Arrival. I need clarification on what it is and what  the requirements are should I plan to travel there. Has anyone on this platform traveled to Nigeria recently in 2018 on the visa on arrival basis and what was your experience like?

Comment: Welcome, Jemima. As this site has a question/answer format, the clarification follows, but, as it is not a forum, the experiences of others might be considered opinion based and the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you may wish to consult the eligibility criteria and visa requirements, as detailed by the [Nigerian Immigration Service](https://immigration.gov.ng/visa-on-arrival/). After determining that you're among those to whom it might be issued, you must initiate the process in advance of any travels (added emphasis mine).

> **Visa on Arrival is issued at the port of entry in Nigeria**.
>
> Note: Successful online payment is not an approval. Applicant should not proceed to Nigeria until receipt of  ‘Visa on Arrival Approval Letter’.
>
> ***The VoA facility is available to frequently travelled High Net Worth Investors and Intending Visitors who may not be able to obtain visa at the Nigerian Missions/Embassies in their countries of residence due to the absence of a Nigerian mission in those countries or exigencies of urgent business travels.***
>
> **Eligibility**
>
> - Frequently travelled Business Persons of International Repute
> - Executives of Multi-national Companies
> - Members of Government Delegations
> - Holders of United Nations Laissez-Passer
> - Holders of African Union Laissez-Passer,
> - Holders of ECOWAS Laissez-Passer,
> - Holders of any other Official travel documents of other recognized International Organizations who intend to visit Nigeria.
>
> Note: Visa on Arrival is available to citizens of all countries except ECOWAS Nationals who do not require visa to visit Nigeria and other countries which Nigeria has entered into visa abolition agreements.
>
> **How to Apply for Visa on Arrival**
>
> **Step 1: Get Visa on Arrival Approval Letter**
>
> There are two methods to obtaining VoA approval letter: applying through email or in person  or application by representative in Nigeria.
>
> **Applying through Email**
>
> Applicant/Representative shall write an Application Letter to The Comptroller General of Immigration, NIS HQ, Abuja stating the following via this email address: oa@nigeriaimmigration.gov.ng
>
> - Name of Applicant indicating Nationality
> - Passport number of Applicant
> - Purpose of visit
> - Proposed date of visit
> - Proposed port of entry
> - Flight itinerary
> - Address in Nigeria or Hotel Reservation
>
> Attach the following documents:
>
> - Copy of Passport Data Page
> - Copy of Airline Return ticket reservation
>
> Note: After Approval, a letter will be forwarded to your email with a copy sent to the Airline stated in your application and Immigration port of entry.
>
> **Applying through your representative in Nigeria**
>
> 1. Contact your Representative (Business partners, Company Representative, Protocol/Liaison Officer, etc) in Nigeria.
> 2. The Representative files a formal request for Visa on Arrival Approval on your behalf by writing an application letter to The Comptroller General of Immigration, NIS HQ, Abuja stating the following:
>
>    - Name of Applicant indicating Nationality, Passport number of visitor
>    - Purpose of visit
>    - Proposed date of visit
>    - Proposed port of entry
>    - Proposed airline
>    - Flight itinerary
>    - Address in Nigeria
>    - Email address of the visitor
>    - Acceptance of Immigration Responsibility
> 3. The representative shall attach the following documents in support of the application
>
>    - Copy of visitor’s passport data page
>    - Copy of Airline Return ticket Reservation
>
> *Note: After Approval Letter is obtained,(Hard Copy) by your representative, copies of the same document will be forwarded to the Airline stated in the application and Immigration port of entry.*
>
> **Step 2: Pay for Visa on Arrival**
>
> Fill in the application form with your correct details and make payment online [here](https://portal.immigration.gov.ng/VisaArrivalProgram/freshVisaOnArrivalProgram).
>
> *Online Payment may also be made at point of arrival subject to presentation of Visa on Arrival Approval Letter. Master Card, Visa and American Express card are acceptable.*
>
> **Step 3: Arrive at the Port of Entry and proceed for Immigration Clearance**
>
> Upon arrival at the Port of Entry, proceed to the desk marked ‘Visa on Arrival’ for issuance of entry Visa. Present the following documents in hard copy at the Port of Entry:
>
> - Visa Approval Letter (Pre-approved visa letter), valid for 14 days from the date of issuance
> - Evidence of online payment
> - Valid Passport with minimum of six months validity
> - Valid return ticket
> - Two recent passport sized photographs
>
> **Timeline:**
>
> The request shall be processed and approval letter issued within 48hrs (2 working days).